# Karate - Passing custom headers in POST request

Tags: karate

I am trying to pass a application specific Headers in my POST request, however I am getting error - Step header XXX-XXX doesn't have a matching glue code.

How can i specify headers which are specific to my application in the request. Here is the sample request that I am submitting:

```
And header X-XSRF-TOKEN = responseCookies["XSRF-TOKEN"].value
And header Accept = 'application/json'
And header X-Requested-With = 'XMLHttpRequest'
And header Referer = 'https://domain123.com/abc/'
And header APP-CHANGE-NUMBER ='123'
```

I am getting error for the APP-CHANGE-NUMBER. Is there a way I can pass custom headers ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use a space after the `=` sign.

```
And header APP-CHANGE-NUMBER = '123'
```